# Rest API Url for Add Entity Form

Tags: rest, api

Let's say we have a website with user entities. If we follow the general standards for `Rest API` we would get some of the following urls:

```
GET /users : View list of users

GET /users/{id} : View specific user

POST /users : Add a new user to list

PUT /users/{id} : Update specific user
```

I have a page that is a form for creating a new user. To follow `Rest API` standards, what should the url be for getting this form? Would `/users/add` be appropriate?

I know the ideal thing would be to have this form as a pop-up modal on the list of users page. But, let's say that's not an option. We must pick a url for getting this page that contains a form for adding a user.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say there's a strict rule about this. I think you can choose the name you want and on my own I did it like you're proposing: `/users/add`, just make sure you are using the same structure for other entities in your project, e.g. `/products/add` - in terms of consistency.

Answer (score 0):

As the answer above, there is no universal rule for it. I tend to make my post urls like this `/user/addNew`